# Loading component template from file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Having the component template as inline HTML isn't very maintainable to me, so I instead want to load it from a file. After some googling it seems I have to use `DOMParser()` to parse the HTML file and put the result of that into the template property.

I found the [following (old) post](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/313) and tried to do the same, but this fails with
`TypeError: vm.$options.template.charAt is not a function`.

This is what I have so far (using `vue-resource`):

**main.js**

```
var asyncComponent = Vue.component('async-component', function (resolve, reject) {
    app.$http.get('./template.html', function(data, status, request){
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
        resolve({
            template: doc
        });
    });
});

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/async', component: asyncComponent }
    ]
})

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

Seeing as `vue-resource` is not maintained anymore, I also tried using `fetch`, but this yielded exactly the same error:

```
var asyncComponent = Vue.component('asyncComponent', function (resolve, reject) {
    fetch('./module.html')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(function(data) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
        resolve({
            template: doc
        });
    });
});
```

How can I load the template from a separate HTML file using native functionality without having to use i.e. webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `template` field should contain the raw HTML string (`DOMParser` is not needed).

*Using `vue-resource`:*

```
app.$http.get('./template.html', function(data, status, request) {
  resolve({
    template: data
  });
});
```

*Using `axios`:*

```
axios.get('./template.html').then(({ data }) => {
  resolve({
    template: data
  }
});
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/q70p7jxol9)